# Extract XML using XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy

Based on help from other questions I've asked, I've got this groovy snippet:

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate( xpathQuery, records, XPathConstants.NODESET );
return nodes.collect { node -> node.getTextContent() }
```

Which allows me to perform `xpathQuery` on `records` and get the result.

What I want to do now is just return (as a string) the raw xml of the result (rather than the text content) (I realise this will not result in a valid xml document).

Such that:

```
xml = "<root><apple><color>RED</color></apple>…</root>"
xpathQuery = "/root/apple[1]"
```

will return:

```
"<apple><color>RED</color></apple>"
```

(Without the enclosing `<apple>` tags would also be fine). Is there a simple way to do this?

Or failing that, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Depending on the XPath engine/API used, a returned XmlNode should have an **outerXml** property -- such as the .NET XmlNode type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx

Comment: Or, if you are using XSLT, just use `<xsl:copy-of>` .

Comment: I'm using javax.xml.xpath which doesn't seem to have an outerXML property

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very elegant, but could possibly be useful:

Use this:

```
concat('<apple><color>', //root/apple[1]/color, '</color></apple>')
```

If you know the structure won't change, or for a more complicated unknown number of child elements within `<apple>`, use:

`//root/apple[1]/node()` to give you all children nodes, and use groovy's [.each](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Foreach_loop) function to iterate through the nodes, and create your string paddings, and combine them with the original `//root/apple[1]/color` result.